# A problem on Intramolecular Cannizzaro's Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, carbonyl-compounds

My textbook has the following reaction given as a special case of Intramolecular Cannizzaro reaction:
[image]

As far as I understand, here one Phenyl group migrates (instead of hydride ion) from the carbonyl getting oxidized to that getting reduced.

My question is, what is making the migration of the phenyl group possible?

Comment: What makes it possible? Ultimately because it is energetically favourable. Plus it is irreversible, so if it occurs there's no way for the product to revert to starting materials

Comment: Well, as you noticed it's basically a Cannizzaro reaction - reasons are the same, but what you want is rather some kind of rationalisation and should specify which.

Comment: This is known as the benzil-benzilic acid rearrangement. As Waylander noted it's energetically favourable. Phenyl group acts as a group with high migratory aptitude in many other reactions too. One can again question as to what makes the migration of hydride possible in the main Cannizzaro reaction.